# Find the number of documents indexed in my oracle.context index?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-text

I know I can use `ctx_query.count_hits` to count the number of document matching a query,
and similarly, I can use

```
count(*) where CONTAINS(...)
```

But these are only options if I actually have a query. Those functions throw an exception if I pass an empty string as a query (thanks oracle...). So,

> Is there a way to count the total number of document indexed by my
>   oracle.text index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way is to use [CTX_REPORT Package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/crptpkg.htm#i996935), either **describe_index**

```
set long 50000
select ctx_report.describe_index('MYINDEX') from dual;
```

will give you the number of indexed documents in `docid count` column:

> ```
> ===========================================================================
>                              INDEX DESCRIPTION
> ===========================================================================
> index name:                    "SCHEMA"."MYINDEX"
> index id:                      1130
> index type:                    context
>
> status:                        INDEXED
>
> full optimize token:
> full optimize count:
> docid count:                   6909265
> nextid:                        6909266
> ```

Alternatively, use **index_stats**:

```
create table output (result CLOB);

  declare
    x clob := null;
  begin
    ctx_report.index_stats('MYINDEX',x);
    insert into output values (x);
    commit;
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(x);
  end;
  /

set long 32000
set head off
set pagesize 10000
select * from output;
```

> ```
> ===========================================================================
>            STATISTICS FOR "SCHEMA"."MYINDEX"
> ===========================================================================
> indexed documents:                                             6,909,265
> ```

Also useful to get the size of the index:

```
set long 50000
select ctx_report.index_size('MYINDEX') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CTX... views:

```
select idx_name, idx_table_owner, idx_table, idx_docid_count 
from ctx_user_indexes
```